# ngOnChanges how the simpleChanges object is handled

Tags: angular, angular5

I am very new to angular 5 I am learning component interaction from the official site it's given

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}) {}
```

And in the life cycle hooks

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {}
```

I understand that SimpleChanges is an object that ngOnChanges gets as an parameter and we can access the previous and current value using it. But I didn't understand how the following is working :

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}) {}
```

I couldn't find any good explanation also anywhere

Answer (score 3):

```
{[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}
```

means: an object with keys of type string, each associated to a value of type SimpleChange.

If your component has 3 inputs a, b and c, and the inputs a and c change, then Angular will call ngOnChanges() with an argument like the following:

```
{
  a: {
    previousValue: ...,
    currentValue: ...,
    firstChange: false
  }
  c: {
    previousValue: ...,
    currentValue: ...,
    firstChange: false
  }
}
```

Comment: So that mean we can define which type of key we want ??

Comment: The key is the name of the input. If the input foo changes, the object will have a key named foo.

Comment: I am sorry but I am getting confused in the first line we are taking the input as an object of type SimpleChange and then we are using it as a value of type SimpleChanges of an object ??

Comment: When I say "input", I'm talking about **the inputs of your component**. Not about the argument of ngOnChanges. I.e. the fields/properties decorated with `@Input()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is only type sugar for argument in ngOnChanges function.

```
{[propKey: string]: SimpleChange
```

Above line means, that the argument is kind of hashmap, where key is a string and the value is a instance of SimpleChange function.

"propKey" is a just a name, instead of that you could also type "aaa", or "myPropKey" and will be still works.

Please look at the https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/12/31/definitive-guide-to-typescript/ abd search for hashmap